# How should I use @pm.stochastic in PyMC?

Tags: python, pymc, mcmc

Fairly simple question: How should I use `@pm.stochastic`? I have read some blog posts that claim `@pm.stochastic`expects a negative log value:

```
@pm.stochastic(observed=True)
def loglike(value=data):
  # some calculations that generate a numeric result
  return -np.log(result)
```

I tried this recently but found really bad results. Since I also noticed that some people used np.log instead of -np.log, I give it a try and worked much better. What is really expecting `@pm.stochastic`? I'm guessing there was a small confusion on the sign required due to a very popular example using something like `np.log(1/(1+t_1-t_0))` which was written as `-np.log(1+t_1-t_0)`

Another question: What is this decorator doing with the `value` argument? As I understand it, we start with some proposed value for the priors that need to enter in the likelihood and the idea of `@pm.stochastic` is basically produce some number to compare this likelihood to the number generated by the previous iteration in the sampling process. The likelihood should receive the `value` argument and some values for the priors, but I'm not sure if this is all `value` is doing because that's the only required argument and yet I can write:

```
@pm.stochastic(observed=True)
def loglike(value=[1]):
  data = [3,5,1] # some data
  # some calculations that generate a numeric result
  return np.log(result)
```

And as far as I can tell, that produces the same result as before. Maybe, it works in this way because I added `observed=True` to the decorator. If I would have tried this in a stochastic variable with `observed=False` by default, `value` would be changed in each iteration trying to obtain a better likelihood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@pm.stochastic` is a decorator, so it is expecting a function.  The simplest way to use it is to give it a function that includes `value` as one of its arguments, and returns a log-likelihood.

You should use the `@pm.stochastic` decorator to define a custom prior for a parameter in your model.  You should use the `@pm.observed` decorator to define a custom likelihood for data.  Both of these decorators will create a `pm.Stochastic` object, which takes its name from the function it decorates, and has all the familiar methods and attributes (here is [a nice article on Python decorators](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)).

Examples:

A parameter `a` that has a triangular distribution a priori:

```
@pm.stochastic
def a(value=.5):
    if 0 <= value < 1:
        return np.log(1.-value)
    else:
        return -np.inf
```

Here `value=.5` is used as the initial value of the parameter, and changing it to `value=1` raises an exception, because it is outside of the support of the distribution.

A likelihood `b` that has is normal distribution centered at `a`, with a fixed precision:

```
@pm.observed
def b(value=[.2,.3], mu=a):
    return pm.normal_like(value, mu, 100.)
```

Here `value=[.2,.3]` is used to represent the observed data.

I've put this together in [a notebook that shows it all in action here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/afca981a3c10f7f1c6e9).

Comment: Thanks. From your answer I see that `@pm.stochastic` expects a function return a np.log value. Is this correct? In your first example of `@pm.stochastic`, which distribution was used to sample `a`? If the sampling process chooses `1`, the variable `a` would raise an exception?

Comment: Q1: correct, a log-likelihood value.  Q2: The first distribution is a triangular distribution, that is not normalized.  Q3: yes, because the log-likelihood is -infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes confusion is easy since the @stochastic returns a likelihood which is the opposite of the error essentially. So you take the negative log of your custom error function and return THAT as your log-likelihood.